# How to enable support of CPU virtualization on Packard bell(AMD Quad-Core Processor A4-5000)

Tags: cpu, virtualization

if a computer CPU doesnt support virtualization(such as AMD Quad-Core Processor A4-5000),is it need to buy new pc  to virtualization?or are there other solutions especially software?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enter to the BIOS menu into your PC and enable the virtualization since according to this page http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Jaguar/AMD-A4-Series%20A4-5000.html your CPU AMD supports it.
[Here is a guide for how to do that](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html).
Hope this helps